# Can't login to Lubuntu 13.10

Tags: ubuntu

After installation of LAMP, I can't login to my account.

I see my login screen (with prompt enter login + password).

But after entering it shows me strange error prompt, but so fast that I can't read what exactly happen. And return again to login screen.

I used `Cntrl + Alt + 1` - login to shell.

And tried to view `/var/log/` logs.

Suspicious line at boot.log:

```
    - starting reload cups, upon starting avahi-daemon to make shure remote queues are populated
```

***Where exactly should I looking for trouble?

Maybe exist other ways to figure out what is wrong?***

Comment: An experienced SO user knows this is off-topic and should be asked on http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

~/.cache/lxsession/Lubuntu/run.log may be a good starting point

The same problem happend to my for the following reasons:

- Not enough space in your home directory  (removing some files will solve the problem)
- Something strange happened with the X and the ~/.Xauthority file is corrupted (removing it will solve the problem)
- A config file corrupted (removing the lxde related config files will solve the problem)

I hope it can help.

Comment: When you tell someone to delete files, especially system/config files, better tell that person to make a **backup** before deleting.

Comment: We are talking about user space config files, but your recomendation remains valid.